# Проверить поддержку события в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Возникла такая задача, проверить существование или поддержку события в разных браузерах.

Например:

Событие `wheel`, оно поддерживается в IE 9+, но если его проверять через, например:

`'onwheel' in document` или `'onwheel' in document.documentElement` или `'onwheel' in window`

то всегда будет возвращаться ложь, только если `onmousewheel` проверять, и тогда вернется истина

или вот еще пример, с `transitionend`, если проверять в document или document.documentElement, то, только мазила вернет истину, а хром вернет истину, только если в window проверить (в IE 10 и 11 всегда ложь, но событие поддерживается)

Есть ли, единый, верный способ проверить, что событие будет поддерживаться?

Еще, есть события с префиксами (вебкит, моз), например

`transitionend` и `webkitTransitionEnd`

Оба работают во всех браузерах (хром, мазила, IE 10 и 11)

Можно использовать их так?

```
el.addEventListener("transitionend", tEnd);
el.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", tEnd);
```

Всегда будет работать один из этих двух, transitionend

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs/#using-modernizr-with-javascript). Там есть такая возможность:


Modernizr.hasEvent

`Modernizr.hasEvent(eventName,[element])`


Modernizr.hasEvent lets you determine if the browser supports a supplied event. By default, it does this detection on a div element

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, Проблема осталась таже( Modernizr, определяет, что transitionend работает только в мазиле